# JSF keeps the same values for all sessions

Tags: spring, jsf

We have problems with JSF in our web application. The scope seems not to work on the JSF ManagedBeans.

We use the scopes to give a different view to different users. We have a form that has a list, fields, etc. We want to add an object to the list but, currently, if another person with a different session is on the same page he can see what we added to our list or what we modified.
The problem is that every ManagedBean lives forever. We tried different scopes but didn't seem to work any of them.

We tried every solution suggested here on Stack Overflow and also the first 3 pages of Google results.

Our Beans are managed by: *javax.annotation.ManagedBean;*

Our configuration:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
    FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.xhtml");
    servletRegistrationBean.setName("Faces Servlet");
    servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return servletRegistrationBean;
}


@Override
public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
    servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.THEME", "rocket");
    servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE", "Development");
    servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.UPLOADER", "commons");
}
```

We use:

```
compile group: 'javax.faces', name: 'javax.faces-api', version: '2.3'
compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.faces', version: '2.3.2'
```

Can you help us understand the problem, or solve the issue?

---

**EDIT:**

Our config class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements ServletContextAware {
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
            applicationContext = app.run(args);
            DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = (DispatcherServlet) applicationContext.getBean("dispatcherServlet");
            dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle it.
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
            JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        dataSource = dataSource();
        emfb.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        emfb.setPackagesToScan("packages");
        return emfb;
    }

    // Database setup - I didn't copy here.


    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.xhtml");
        servletRegistrationBean.setName("Faces Servlet");
        servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }


    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.THEME", "rocket");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE", "Development");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.UPLOADER", "commons");
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean FileUploadFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(new org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter());
        registration.setName("PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter");
        return registration;
    }

    @Configuration
    public class webMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/home.xhtml");
        }
    }
}
```

Our 'view' controller:

```
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
public class PresenceController {

    @Autowired
    private PresenceService ps;

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PresenceController.class);

    private List<String> presenceList;

    private Date startPeriod;

    public void populate() {
        // This will return a List<String> with different strings.
        presenceList = ps.listOfPresences(startPeriod));
    }
    
    // Getters and setters
}
```

Our xhtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
   xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" encoding="UTF-8">
   <html>
      <h:head>
      </h:head>
      <h:body>
         <ui:composition template="layout.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="contentWrap">
               <h:form id="display">
                  <p:calendar id="startPeriod"
                     value="#{presenceController.startPeriod}" navigator="true"
                     pattern="#{resourceHandler.getString('menu.timepattern')}"
                     yearRange="c-100:c-0" mask="true" placeholder="From" />
                  <p:commandButton value="Get data"
                     action="#{presenceController.populate()}" update="display tbl" />
                  <p:dataTable id="tbl" var="pdto"
                     value="#{presenceController.presenceList}"
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {Exporters}"
                     paginator="true" rows="10" style="margin-bottom:20px">
                     <f:facet name="{Exporters}">
                        <h:commandLink>
                           <h:graphicImage value="assets/img/excel.png"
                              style="height:30px;widht:30px;bottom:25px" />
                           <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tbl"
                              fileName="filename" />
                        </h:commandLink>
                        <h:commandLink>
                           <p:graphicImage value="assets/img/pdf.png" width="24" />
                           <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl"
                              fileName="filename" />
                        </h:commandLink>
                     </f:facet>
                     <p:column id="lastName" headerText="#{resourceHandler.getString('attendance.lastname')}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{pdto.lastName}" />
                     </p:column>
                     <p:column id="firstName" headerText="#{resourceHandler.getString('attendance.firstname')}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{pdto.firstName}" />
                     </p:column>
                     <p:column id="mounth" headerText="#{resourceHandler.getString('attendance.mounth')}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{pdto.mounth}" />
                     </p:column>
                     <p:column id="day" headerText="#{resourceHandler.getString('attendance.day')}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{pdto.day}" />
                     </p:column>
                     <p:column id="starttime" headerText="#{resourceHandler.getString('attendance.beginning')}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{pdto.startTimeHoure}:#{pdto.startTimeMin}" />
                     </p:column>
                     <p:column id="endtime" headerText="#{resourceHandler.getString('attendance.end')}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{pdto.endTimeHoure}:#{pdto.endTimeMin}" />
                     </p:column>
                     <p:column id="elapsed" headerText="#{resourceHandler.getString('attendance.elapsed')}">
                        <h:outputText
                           value="#{pdto.elapsedTimeHoure}:#{pdto.elapsedTimeMin}" />
                     </p:column>
                     <p:column id="signo" headerText="Signo" width="0"
                        styleClass="vd-hidden-column">
                     </p:column>
                  </p:dataTable>
               </h:form>
            </ui:define>
         </ui:composition>
      </h:body>
   </html>
</f:view>
```

As you can see we use Spring Boot as a back-end, alongside the JSF and PrimeFaces as the front-end.

Comment: `Our Beans are managed by: javax.annotation.ManagedBean;` this is wrong... Google on it (add 'stackoverflow' to the query) and you'll get the answer. But then most likely you have other things wrong since just this would not result in the behaviour you experience. [mcve]  please then

Comment: Thank you. I provided the example, as you suggested. I hope that I done it correctly.

Comment: Read my previous comment, the first part (javax.annotation.ManagedBean is wrong). And you misssed an important tag (Spring) since lots of your 'mcve' (it is not really one) is Spring and not jsf

Comment: Yes, I started the debugging with that. I didn't finished that yet. But because you said that 'most likely you have other things wrong' I posted the example.

Comment: I understand, but posting an example is not what an 'mcve' is. There is 'minimal' in it too (is the datatable relevant to the problem? most likely not and certainly not with 8 fields). The `p:calendar`? What if you remove the template? And with all you show, I'm surprised `#{presenceController.populate()}` works... Sure you don't have an applicationContext.xml where you declare beans or something?

Comment: And I think you just have a coding problem in `ps.listOfPresences(startPeriod));`...

Comment: Thank you. I recreate then from scratch and I will post it as soon as I done with it.
Do you suggest to remove this "example"?

Comment: @Kukeltje Finally the issue seems to be solved. The problem was, as you mentioned, that we managed our beans in an incorrect way.

Comment: Great it works... I'll send you an invoice ;-). Was part of the cause not visibible in the code above? If so, you see why the need for an [mcve] is always there. And please use good tutorials next time...